# ssh to another host and run a command

Tags: ssh, password-less

I have been able to successfully set-up password-less ssh from host A to host B. 
Now I want a script that I run on host A that goes to B and then reads a file or just does something on host B and returns back to A.
On host A:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh hostB
echo "$hostname"
ssh hostA
```

But I just see that this script just lands me on hostB and doesn't perform the echo as I intended it to.

Can someone please suggest what's to be done in such a case? I have gone through some suggestions on using sshpass. But since these are Production hosts, there is a fair bit of paper trail I need to go through to install anything on the hosts and the deadlines are looming to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Answered this question: -
Just needed the following 
ssh  
Also to note that no $pwd or ./ references hold good on the absolute path . So if there is a script that you are running on the remote host with such references , make sure to change the script so the absolute path is mentioned instead of those references